# How can I know thread names that run on specific core

Tags: linux, process, ps, thread

I am working in Java code. My code makes specific Java threads run on specific cores. In this code, I give names to Java threads. I need a Linux command that enables me to know the threads' names that run on a specific core.

I use `ps -mo pid,tid,fname,user,psr -p command`, so I know the name of the *process* (java), but I do not know the name corresponding to *tid* to check if the specific thread runs on the core that I determine for that thread.

Answer (score 4):

How about `ps -eL -o user,pid,psr,comm,args`.

`psr` field gives you the processor currently assigned to that thread.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I found out unix tools are not able to retrieve Java thread names.

What helped in my case was:

```
<JDK_HOME>/bin/jcmd 52037 Thread.print
```

Check [jcmd documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html) for more.